# Using JOIN in SQL with a bound

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm new to SQL and I have a question about JOINs.

The question goes like this, There are 2 tables, The first table stores data about ***Patients*** and there is an attribute in the patient table called ***Field,*** which stores the medical field under which the patient was treated. The second table is called ***Doctors,*** and here there is an attribute called ***Specialization,*** which stores the medical field in which the doctor specializes.

Medical fields i.e Cardiology, Virology, and so on.

There can be more doctors who practice in the same specialization.

If I were to join the tables on the basis of the Doctors.Specialization and Patients.Field and a constraint of that each doctor will be matched with a maximum of 5 patients, Then what would be the query?

```
SELECT *
FROM Patients
inner join Doctors on Patients.Diagnosis = Doctors.Specialization;
```

Comment: which database engine?

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` or a lateral join to filter out rows. What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it like this:

1. Join the two tables using specialization and diagnosis columns.
2. Rank doctors and patients by specialization using DENSE_RANK() analytic function
3. Filter the data. Patients' ranks must be in a range which's:

   - lower bound (exclusive) is: (doctors' rank - 1) * 5.

     - If doctor's rank is 1, then it's 0.
     - If doctor's rank is 2, then it's 5.
   - upper bound (inclusive) is: doctors' rank * 5.

     - If doctor's rank is 1, then it's 5.
     - If doctor's rank is 2, then it's 10.

```
WITH base AS (
  SELECT d.specialization,
         d.id AS doctor_id,
         d.name AS doctor_name,
         p.id AS patient_id,
         p.name AS patient_name,

         -- Rank doctors by specialization.
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY d.specialization
            ORDER BY d.id
         ) AS doc_spec_rank,

         -- Rank patients by specialization
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY d.specialization
            ORDER BY p.id
         ) AS patient_spec_rank
  
  FROM doctors d
  INNER JOIN patients p
    ON d.specialization = p.diagnosis
)

SELECT *
FROM base
WHERE (
  (doc_spec_rank - 1) * 5 < patient_spec_rank
  AND doc_spec_rank * 5 >= patient_spec_rank
)
ORDER BY specialization, doc_spec_rank, patient_spec_rank
;
```

Since you didn't provide your rbdms and test data, I took the liberty of creating a sample schema in Oracle 18c.

Here's a fiddle with the schema and the solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/4_kikOO7